# How do I convert this nested json to CSV using Python and Panda?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am fairly new to python and panda, and I am trying to convert these json files to CSV

The json file I have managed to flatten:

```
        "empnum1244": {
        "user_name": "keane@a",
        "name": "Keane",
        "flag": true,
        "list": x
    },
    "empnum1255": {
        "user_name": "julia@a",
        "name": "Julia",
        "flag": true,
        "list": x
    },
```

I have no trouble converting these through reset index:

```
df = pd.read_json ('dups3.json',orient='index')
df.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
```

The double nested json I am having trouble with:

```
{    "aaron@gmail.com": {
        "employeenumber5566": {
            "user_name": "1234sysidAaron",
            "name": "Aaron",
            "flag": true,
            "list": x
        },
        "employeenumber6677": {
            "user_name": "Aaron@gmail.com",
            "name": "Aaron",
            "flag": true,
            "list": x
        }
    },
    "Ahmish@gmail.com": {
        "employeenumber890": {
            "user_name": "144sysidAhmish",
            "name": "Ahmish",
            "flag": true,
            "list": x
        },
        "employeenumber23457": {
            "user_name": "ahmish@gmail.com",
            "name": "ahmish",
            "flag": true,
            "list": x
        }
    }
    
}
```

How do I flatten these out with 2 level of indexes? My desired output is:

```
Email            |   EmpID             |       User_name     |      Name       |   flag    | list
Ahmish@gmail.com   employeenumber890     144sysidAhmish          Ahmish           True         x
Ahmish@gmail.com   employeenumber23457   ahmish@gmail.com        ahmish           True         x
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use list comprehension to flatten the nested data

```
import json

d  = json.loads(data)
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Email': email, 'EmpID': empid, **y}
                   for email, v in d.items() for empid, y in v.items()])
```

---

```
print(df)

              Email                EmpID         user_name    name  flag list
0   aaron@gmail.com   employeenumber5566    1234sysidAaron   Aaron  True    x
1   aaron@gmail.com   employeenumber6677   Aaron@gmail.com   Aaron  True    x
2  Ahmish@gmail.com    employeenumber890    144sysidAhmish  Ahmish  True    x
3  Ahmish@gmail.com  employeenumber23457  ahmish@gmail.com  ahmish  True    x
```

Comment: Hey really appreciate the input! I have some questions in line 4, df = pd.DataFrame([{'Email': email, 'EmpID': empid, **y} , I suppose we are labeling email to "Email" and empid to "EmpID", but how are we doing that? 

The json file doesn't have a column name for    "aaron@gmail.com:", "employeenumber5566": and "employeenumber6677": , they are all unique values for each of those json object

Comment: We are not labeling `email` to `Email`, here `email` is a variable name whose value is obtained by iterating over the key-value pairs for the top level dictionary. So if you consider first dictionary the key would be `"aaron@gmail.com"` and therefore the value of `email` would be the same as that key.